# How to initialize a bool pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm coding something small to understand how pointers work and have reached an issue.
I have a boolean pointed to by "valid" in a file called "main.c":

```
bool *valid;
```

The pointer's address is passed to a method in a second file called "test.c":

```
method(&valid);
```

Inside the "test.c" method I set valid to true:

```
*valid = true;
```

After the method call in "main.c" I dereference valid in two if statements to see if it's true or false:

```
if (*valid) {
    printf("valid is true.\n");
}
if (!(*valid)) {
    printf("valid is false.\n");
}
```

Both statements print, but only "valid is true" should. What could be the issue here?

Comment: If you are using *valid=true then you do not want to use the addressof operator when passing the pointer to method().

Comment: What does your compiler tell you about this?

Comment: Posting a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help. I'm pretty certain that your compiler warnings are already telling you the answer.

Comment: If you pass `&valid` to a function, then `*valid` within that function is not a bool. Maybe you show a complete example what you are doing. And if the compiler yells a warning at you, take care!

Comment: C does not support _methods_.

Comment: sample [code](http://ideone.com/HbqvVv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the declaration of `valid` is indeed a `bool *`, then in the `main` function, you have declared something to *point at* a `bool` without declaring a `bool` itself. Until you initialize it, it will initially point at an unpredictable memory location.

When you pass this into `method`, assuming your code compiles, `method` must be accepting a `bool **` -- a pointer to a pointer to bool -- so when you set `*valid = true`, what you are actually doing is setting the `bool *` pointer in the `main` method to the value of `true`, which is 0x0000000000000001. When `main` dereferences the pointer, it reads bytes at that memory location and interprets them as `bool`. A property-formed `bool` must be either 0 or 1, and the compiler makes assumptions based on this when evaluating things such as the `!` operator -- as such, a value that is not either 0 or 1 can cause those assumptions to break down, and can result in both `value` and `!value` being seen as "true".

What you want to do is declare `valid` as a plain `bool` in the `main` function. This declaration will actually allocate space for a `bool`, rather than allocating space to *point at* a `bool` without allocating the `bool` itself. Then, `method` accepts a `bool *`, and when it does `*valid = true`, it is assigning `true` to the `bool` declared on `main`'s stack.

Comment: You are most welcome. :-)